# generating UUID in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to generate UUID in pl/pgsql and I have written this block of code. I have no error but I cant see the UUID in output and the message does not rais too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generatesurrogat() RETURNS uuid[] AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
uid UUID;
BEGIN
uid:=(select uuid_generate_v1());
RAISE NOTICE 'My UUID is',uid;
return uid;
END$BODY$
```

could you please tell me how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you return an array? Shouldn't that bee `returns uuid`? And what exactly do you mean with "*I can't see the UUID in output*"

Comment: I want to generate an UUID value and then I want to see this value as an output. I want, if I run this function, I can see UUID value in data section output

Comment: You do have `client_min_messages` set to `notice`, see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES   (And again: why do you return an array from that function, it makes no sense).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I change from an aary to a simple UUID, but where can I find **cleint_min_message**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function worked like a charm

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generatesurrogat() RETURNS uuid AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
uid UUID;
BEGIN
uid:=(select uuid_generate_v1());
RAISE NOTICE 'My UUID is %',uid;
return uid;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

You missed a `%` in your `RAISE NOTICE` syntax. Also you missed the **language specification**

I assume you are using PGAdmin3. If so you can find the message in the ***output pane's*** ***message tab***.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do u find the messages tab? If not try giving ctrl+Alt+V to get a default view of the editor.